# CSV file getting deleted from AEM PUBLISH on code deployment

Tags: csv, aem, aem-6, dam, aem-core-wcm-components

I have created a Form using AEM component.

I save the details provided by the user in a CSV file in /content/dam/... of Publish environment.

While the data gets fetched properly but when the code gets deployed again, the CSV file gets removed and the Data is lost.

If anyone has any solution for the same, please help me out.

Regards

I have not got any probable cause for this issue on internet and thus tried posting here.

Comment: *"when the code gets deployed again"* - is pretty vague. how did you deploy the code? any specific jcr path affected by the deployment? also, why haven't you setup a reverse replication to take the data on publish to author?

Comment: Is this AEMaaCS, on-premise? Any packages that overwrite the path where you save the file?

Answer (score -1):

You should check the paths of filter.xml files in your project. One of them must be overwriting your "/content/dam/..." path.